# loading progress form submit using sweetalert

Tags: javascript, html, sweetalert2

I would like to render a waiting time animation when submitting a form, but I prefer to use `SweetAlert` rather than a standard loading image.

This the basic code:

```js
$("form").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // stops the default action
            $("#loader").show(); // shows the loading screen
            $.ajax({
                url: test.php,
                type: "POST"
                success: function (returnhtml) {
                    $("#loader").hide(); // hides loading sccreen in success call back
                }
            });
        });
```

This is the code SweetAlert wants to implement:

```js
window.swal({
  title: "Checking...",
  text: "Please wait",
  imageUrl: "images/ajaxloader.gif",
  showConfirmButton: false,
  allowOutsideClick: false
});

//using setTimeout to simulate ajax request
setTimeout(() => {
  window.swal({
    title: "Finished!",
    showConfirmButton: false,
    timer: 1000
  });
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert-dev.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css" />
```

plz someone make the tips for doing this

Comment: It isn't clear to me what your question is. Can you please ask a more specific question, rather than "someone make the tips for doing this"?

Comment: @PhilipRaath my question is using sweetalert rather than loader gif take a look and run the second snippet

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You were almost there! Just replace the `#loader` code with the sweet alert code.

```js
$("form").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // stops the default action
            //$("#loader").show(); // shows the loading screen
            window.swal({
              title: "Checking...",
              text: "Please wait",
              imageUrl: "images/ajaxloader.gif",
              showConfirmButton: false,
              allowOutsideClick: false
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: test.php,
                type: "POST"
                success: function (returnhtml) {
                    //$("#loader").hide(); // hides loading sccreen in success call back
                    window.swal({
                      title: "Finished!",
                      showConfirmButton: false,
                      timer: 1000
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```